# Operations Dashboard's Embed Content clickable

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard

I want to have images in my dashboard such that I can zoom into those images. I realised that embed content don't have a functionality as such, so I am looking for a way so that I can make my images clickable which will allow them to open into a new tab. From there I can easily zoom in/out.

Currently Operations Dashboard only takes image URL as parameter. All I need is to add an anchor tag with same URL and target="_blank" attirbute.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

For what you are after, I suggest you use a [Rich Text element](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/operations-dashboard/help/rich-text.htm) instead. In the text editor, click **<> Source** to insert HTML. Then, do what you were describing; add an anchor tag `<a>` with an image tag `<img>` inside of it.

```
<a href="https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/1-1-Cal-OES.png" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/1-1-Cal-OES.png"/>
</a>
```

You can also add in width and height properties like they did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139811/how-to-link-an-image-and-target-a-new-window).